# Magento sort using percentage discount

Tags: sorting

I am new to magento, please tell me How can I add a sorting option to my product listing page which will automatically calculate percentage discount using Special Price and Original Price and will sort according to the discount percentage

Answer (score 5):

First add a dummy attribute called 'discount_percent' and make it "used for sorting" ([just as Giuseppe said in the other answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/25600/146)).
It's not important what type it is or what values it has.
it's easier that way. If you don't want to add the attribute you have to rewrite the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Config::getAttributeUsedForSortByArray` to include your attribute. I would rather avoid rewrites as much as possible.
Now you need to tell magento to take a special action when the sorting is done by that attribute.
For this you have to rewrite (I don't know other way) the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addAttributeToSort()`
You will need a new module for that. let's call it `Easylife_Sorting`.
Here are the files.

`app/etc/module/Easylife_Sorting.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Sorting>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Sorting>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Sorting/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Sorting>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Easylife_Sorting>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_collection>Easylife_Sorting_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</product_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Sorting/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php` - your class override. Here is where the magic happens.

```
class Easylife_Sorting_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection {
    public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC){
        //don't screw up the admin sorting
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID){
            return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
        }
        if ($attribute == 'discount_percent') {
            //determine the discount percent value
            $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('discount_percent_value', '(({{price}} - final_price) / {{price}})', array('price'));
            //sort by the discount percent value
            $sortDir = $dir;
            //in case you need to reverse the order so when you sort ascending you will see the most discounts first do this:
            //if not then remove the if-else statement below.
            if ($sortDir == self::SORT_ORDER_ASC) {
                $sortDir = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC;
            }
            else {
                $sortDir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC;
            }
            $this->getSelect()->order(array('discount_percent_value '.$sortDir));
            return $this;
        }
        //otherwise do nothing special
        return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
    }
}
```

This works for sure for simple/virtual/downloadable products. I have no idea what effect has on configurable/bundle and grouped products.

Comment: I'm guessing for configurable products it'll just use the default price. Not sure about bundle

Answer (score 1):

it is not an easy task if you are new to magento !

You should add an attribute "discount_percent" and let it be usable for sorting.

Then you have two option.
1) when you change price manually calculate and set the discount_percent value

2) write a module that listen to the "product_before_save" event and calculate and
update the discount_percent value.

Comment: can you take a look here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358076/how-to-add-sort-options-in-back-end-grid-as-shown-in-pictures

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution for SORT products collection by BEST DISCOUNT

```
$today = date('Y-m-d',time());
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price',array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $today),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $today),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'special_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'special_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                )
            )
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter();


        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

and add ORDER by discount

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('discount_different'=>'(`e`.`price` - `e`.`special_price`)'))->order(array('discount_different DESC'))->group('e.entity_id');
```

Also can try this

```
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
                    'discount_value',
                    '({{price}} - price_index.final_price)',
                    array('price'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that worked for simple and grouped products

```
if ($attribute == 'discount_percent') {
        $sortDir = $dir;
        /*if ($sortDir == self::SORT_ORDER_ASC) {
            $sortDir = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC;
        }
        else {
            $sortDir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC;
        }*/

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('related' => 'catalog_product_relation'),
            'related.parent_id = e.entity_id',
            array()
        )
        ->joinLeft(
            array('status' => 'catalog_product_entity_int'),
            'status.entity_id = related.child_id and status.attribute_id = 96 and status.store_id = 0 ',
            array()
        )
        ->joinLeft(
            array('related_price' => 'catalog_product_index_price'),
            'related.child_id = related_price.entity_id and price_index.website_id = related_price.website_id '
                . 'AND price_index.customer_group_id = related_price.customer_group_id ',
            array()
        )
        ->where('status.value = '.Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED.' or status.value is null')
        ->columns(array(
            'discount_percent_value' => new Zend_Db_Expr('GREATEST(COALESCE(((price_index.price - price_index.final_price) / price_index.price),0), COALESCE(((related_price.price - related_price.final_price) / related_price.price), 0))'),
        ))
        ->order(array('discount_percent_value '.$sortDir))
        ->group(array(
            'e.entity_id'
        ));

        return $this;
    }
```